# Laravel 5.6 update pivot table column without updating existing values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

Im using this code to update the ExisitingPivot and it works fine.

Here's what I have so far:

```
auth()->user()->Formations()->updateExistingPivot($formation->id, array(
  'score' => $score, 
  'temps_quiz' => $temps, 
  'date_sortie' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(), 
  'tentative' => $tentative)
);
```

After using attach to insert the 2nd row , i want to make an update juste on the last pivot row but it updates the two rows.
i used last() but it dosent' work .

Can anyone suggest where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Show us your attempt with `last` please

Comment: i just added ->last() after Formtion() auth()->user()->Formations()->last->updateExistingPivot @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: `updateExistingPivot()` function will update all the rows with the given `id`, if you want custom update use eloquent query

Comment: @LaadhariAmine
I'm sure it is updating two rows because that user record has 2 rows from formations. then it will update all it's related formations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `updateExistingPivot()` function will update all the rows with the given `id`, if you want custom update you could use the eloquent query like :

```
auth()->user()->Formations()->where('formation_id', $formation->id)->last()
    ->update( array(
             'score' => $score, 
             'temps_quiz' => $temps, 
             'date_sortie' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(), 
             'tentative' => $tentative ));
```